# How do i make grease pencil lines to disappear?

Tags: grease-pencil

i am Doing projection mapping with blender and need to trace a car by having different lines coming and going. how do i make grease pencil lines to disappear. as i only can figure out how to build the whole animation but not make the lines go away in the time line. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the "N" properties menu, go to colours and delete the colour which the stroke is using, and this deletes the strokes.

[image]